# How to stop a tcl script on error?

Tags: tcl

Bash shell uses **-e** switch to stop the execution when there is an error during execution of the current command. Is there a similar way to do the same thing in tcl or should I use **catch** command?

Comment: I use `catch`, but you also have [`try`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/try.htm) available, and maybe some others I'm not aware of.

Comment: Default behavior for a Tcl script is to exit if an uncaught exception is raised. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I use the tcl shell of an EDA tool.

Comment: It does not exit if a command fails to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a shell-like tool that runs Tcl script and it does not have any option to quit on errors, then yes, you will have to catch errors yourself and call `exit` from within the error handler. You can use either the `catch` or the `try` command to do so.

Documentation: [catch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.htm), [exit](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exit.htm), [try](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/try.htm)